# How check if the array is full and only add to it if it's not?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I've got an array which I can add to and check if it is full. After checking if it is full, how would I add to the array if it's not full and ignore the call if it is full?

For example: if not full, add a spy to the array.
The array can't exceed 10 spies, so once it has filled that's it. I want to check whether it is full or not. If it's not, then add a spy. How do I do this? I thought I might be able to advance on the `isFull` method I have, but I'm not sure.

```
public class ConcreteSubject extends AbstractSubject {

    public int arySize;
    private int i = 0;

    private static AbstractSpy[] spies;

    public ConcreteSubject(int a) {
        arySize = a;
        spies = new AbstractSpy[a];
    }

    @Override
    public void addSpy(AbstractSpy spy) {
        if (spies.length < 10) {
            spies[i] = spy;
            System.out.println("spy added at index " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void isFull() {
        boolean b = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < spies.length; i++) {
            if (spies[i] == null) {
                b = true;
            }
        }

        if (!b) {
            System.out.println("Array is full");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array not full");
        }
    }

    @Override
    void notifySpies() {

    }
}



public class TestSpies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConcreteSubject cs = new ConcreteSubject(9);
        AbstractSpy spy = new ConcreteSpy();

        AbstractSpy[] spies = new AbstractSpy[10];

        cs.addSpy(spy);
        cs.addSpy(spy);
        cs.addSpy(spy);

        cs.isFull();

    }
}
```